# Issue with Android TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am creating a custom toggle switch i all most done with the design and the functionality but there is one thing blocking me, I tried to add animation on toggle to the thumb basically a button the animation towards right works perfect but the issue is with the animation towards left here is the code I am using to play both animations.

```
    private void playToggleanimation()
    {
        if(toggleAnimation != null && !toggleAnimation.hasEnded())
        {
            toggleAnimation.setAnimationListener(null);
            toggleAnimation.cancel();
        }
        View v = findViewById(button);
        toggleAnimation = (checked) ? new TranslateAnimation(v.getLeft(), getMeasuredWidth() / 2, 0, 0) : new TranslateAnimation(v.getLeft(), 0, 0, 0);
        toggleAnimation.setAnimationListener(listener);
        toggleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        toggleAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        toggleAnimation.setDuration(250);
        v.clearAnimation();
        v.startAnimation(toggleAnimation);
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the "issue with animation towards left"?Is it moving or not?

Comment: it is not animating just jumping from current position to the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out the issue was with the `getLeft()` method, instead of using this line

```
toggleAnimation = (checked) ? new TranslateAnimation(v.getLeft(), getMeasuredWidth() / 2, 0, 0) : new TranslateAnimation(v.getLeft(), 0, 0, 0);
```

I used below line of code to create animation, it worked fine.

```
toggleAnimation = (checked) ? new TranslateAnimation(v.getLeft(), getMeasuredWidth() / 2, 0, 0) : new TranslateAnimation(getMeasuredWidth() / 2, 0, 0, 0);
```

The `getLeft()` method was always returning 0.